# Reverse BelongsToMany relationship subquery fails to filter properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

getRelationExistenceQueryForSelfJoin() issued by a Filament Resource is returning always a collection of all possible records, due to possibly some problem in the AND NOT EXISTS subquery performed in the same table. So far the relationship is known to be correct as it works in every other section but this.

```html
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `catalogue_items` 
WHERE
    `is_accessory` = 1 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        `catalogue_items` AS `laravel_reserved_0`
        INNER JOIN `compatibilities_pivot` ON `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `compatibilities_pivot`.`id_item` 
    WHERE
        `catalogue_items`.`id` = `compatibilities_pivot`.`id_assoc` 
        AND `catalogue_items`.`id` = 154 
        AND `is_accessory` = 0 
        AND `laravel_reserved_0`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    ) 
    AND `catalogue_items`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY
    `code` ASC
```

Subquery would work correctly if `AND catalogue_items.id = 154` is turned into `AND catalogue_items.id <> 154`. But of course the query is being built by the module so I have no way to make any change anyway.

Models with relationships:

```
class Product extends CatalogueItem
{
    protected $fillable = ['code', 'description', 'image', 'name'];
    protected $attributes = ['is_accessory' => false];

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)->where(
            'is_accessory',
            '=',
            false
        );
    }

    public function accessories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Accessory::class,
            'compatibilities_pivot',
            'id_item',
            'id_assoc'
        );
    }
}
```

```
 
    class Accessory extends CatalogueItem
    {
        use HasBelongsToManySelfRelation;
        protected $attributes = ['is_accessory' => true];
    
        public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
        {
            return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)->where(
                'is_accessory',
                '=',
                true
            );
        }
    
        public function products(): BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(
                Product::class,
                'compatibilities_pivot',
                'id_assoc',
                'id_item'
            );
        }
    
    }
```